# C# store reference to List<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting, compiler-errors

I have a large Quad Tree structure, made from generic lists (`List<T>`) pointing to more lists and so on. These lists are contained in a class: `TreeNode<T>`

In one such tree I store objects of type `GameObject`.

In order to make tree updates faster, I want to store a pointer / reference to the containing `TreeNode` on each `GameObject`, however... I'm coming across issues caused by the generic type `<T>` of the `TreeNode`.

Here is where I have the issue (inside the `TreeNode` class):

```
contents.Add(typedObject);
if (typedObject is GameObject)
{
    GameObject gameObject = (GameObject) (object) typedObject;
    gameObject.treeNode = this;
}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'TreeNode<T>' to 'TreeNode<GameObject>'
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit -->
The node is stored on the `GameObject` as follows:

```
public TreeNode<GameObject> treeNode;
```

Comment: Little bit Off-Topic but....the last time i implemented a quad tree every node has been in on large array. This speeds up the quad tree a lot. Edit: It has been a full-expanded quad-tree. ( Better performance, more memory consumption )

Comment: Can you post the code for GameObject or at least the part relating to the treeNode property?

Comment: Felix: Thanks, memory shouldn't be an issue so that could help. I guess I could then store the array index on the GameObject to point to it?

Comment: So is node the property on the GameObject or is it treeNode as in your first snippet?

Comment: @Arachin You can still use the direct reference. If you wish you can use the index. The benefit of a full-expanded-quad-tree is the speed when moving, sorting and accessing GameObjects. I didn't find the original source, but maybe i gonna look for the code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the type of the `TreeNode<T>` i would suggest to create a non-generic base class. Then you can simply store the reference in the GameObject.

#### Casting

I would avoid it but you can cast the `TreeNode<T>` to `TreeNode<GameObject>` by using the operator `as` as follows:

```
gameObject.treeNode = this as TreeNode<GameObject>;
```

Comment: Yea, if there's no elegant solution, that's my fall-back option.

Comment: Re Edit: I get the same sort of error (`Cannot convert type` vs. `Cannot implicitly convert type`)

Comment: @Arachin Try `as` or cast it first to an object.

Comment: Brilliant, the 'as' works perfectly. Didn't even know about this keyword, thanks :)
Not sure if you want to repost the answer for simplicity. `gameObject.treeNode = this as TreeNode<GameObject>;` worked great.

Comment: @Arachin edited my post for more clarity but kept the other possibilities for ppl who might face the same issue.